# Delete column in a table by clicking cell in another table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two tables: one-row table standing above the multi-column table. I want to delete a column in a multi-column table by clicking the cell in a one-row table that is standing right above this column.

I am trying to do this by using this code:

```
$('.del-column').delegate('td', 'click', function() {
    var index = this.cellIndex;
    $(this).closest('.my-table').find('tr').each(function() {
        this.removeChild(this.cells[ index ]);
    });
});
```

Where .my-table is a multi-column table and .del-column is a one-column table. Any ideas why it does not work?

[Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mozghovyi/bgfvn8aw/3/) where I am trying to do this. And [here is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m8Rn.jpg) an explanation in the image.

Comment: `delegate()` is deprecated since Version 3.0. Use `on()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `delegate()` is deprecated. You need to use `on()` instead.

To fix your actual issue, you need to fix the DOM traversal logic you use, as the `.my-table` is not a parent of the clicked cell, but a child of a sibling of the parent `div`. You can also use the `:nth-child()` selector to get the `td` elements in the column without having to loop. Try this

```
$('.del-column').on('click', '.del', function() {
  var index = this.cellIndex + 1;
  $(this).closest('div').siblings('div.canvas').find('table tr td:nth-child(' + index + ')').remove();
  $(this).remove();
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/bgfvn8aw/4/)

Also note that the HTML for this is very over-complicated. It can be achieved much more simply by using a single table. It will also help the layout stay aligned too.

Comment: thank you for all the comments! It works flawlessly if I delete 2nd, 3rd and any other column. But if I delete the first column (from the left) and then try to add new columns with the yellow button - the Undefined cells start to appear. Here is the printscreen: https://imgur.com/BiuSm7Z Probably the reason is somewhere in my css? I have the same issue with the rows. As for the html, thank you! Now I can see that I could make it one table and adjust necessary issues with CSS. But, I will probably tackle this later when I figure out how javascript works properly on the current layout.

Comment: That problem is because you're appending `$('.del-column-td').html()` to the new cells. If you've deleted all the cols/rows, that doesn't exist so you get `undefined` instead. To fix this just append `-` instead: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/bgfvn8aw/9/

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).closest('.my-table')` will not work, because `.my-table` is not the ancestor of `.del-column`. Try like below.

```
$('.del-column').on('click', 'td', function() {
    var index = this.cellIndex;

    $('.my-table').find('tr').each(function() {
        this.removeChild(this.cells[ index ]);
    });
    $(this).remove();
});
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bgfvn8aw/11/)**

Answer (score 1):

You could loop also through them like this and see if the index matches.

```
var upperTable = document.querySelector(".del-column");
var lowerRows = document.querySelectorAll(".my-table tr")

function removeCorresponding(event) {
  upperIndex = event.target.cellIndex;
  lowerRows.forEach(function(row) {
    row.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(function(lowerCell, lowerIndex) {
      if (upperIndex === lowerIndex) {
        lowerCell.remove();
        event.target.remove()
      }
    });
  });
}

upperTable.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(function(cell, upperIndex) {
  cell.addEventListener("click", removeCorresponding);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rt9oju8b/1/

Comment: thank you! this is a very interesting solution via simple JavaScript. But when I delete the initial columns, the "delete" buttons stop deleting, when I add the new ones using "add" button...

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/rt9oju8b/2/
I have updated the fiddle with an add column button.